# Facebook Chat or Chat in site

Tags: facebook, chat

I will put my site Facebook Chat or Normal chat for users.However, I want to believe that this will be benefical. Is there a graph for that shows it increase pageviews for sites?

I really need it

Comment: Please post your question in details, and for tracking your page views you can try using Google Analytics...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find any chart or data showing that a chat room increases the number of users of your site. In fact, it would be difficult to create a chat room going without having enough users there to support it first.

However, if you already have a significant number of users a chat room could be a good idea.

But I don't think you should be trying to link the use of a chat room with an increase of site users, as that is not always the case.

Comment: I've never really touched on chat rooms as such but in the past have used forums which can increase pageviews but only if as @Sherwin Flight says you have enough users to suport it. Nothing worse than having a chat room or a forum that you are the only person in!